# How can jenkins find junit.xml in a zip file?

Tags: junit, jenkins

I am running Jenkins on a script, that generates a junit.xml report file and other files. However, all those files are zipped by the script, hence Jenkins cannot find it.

Is there a way to make Jenkins unzip the .zip file , find my particular junit file and generate the run results ?

All this is in Linux.

Thanks

Comment: What OS? What creates the zip?

Comment: Edited the question, all of it in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins has the ability to execute arbitrary shell commands as a build step, just add the 'Execute Shell' step to your build and put in the commands you want (presumably 'unzip' would be among them).

Once you've extracted the xml, provided your internal tool generates it using [this schema](https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/trunk/hudson/dtkit/dtkit-format/dtkit-junit-model/src/main/resources/com/thalesgroup/dtkit/junit/model/xsd/junit-4.xsd) the [JUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) just needs the path you extracted to and it will show the results on the build page.

If you have the option, I would really suggest executing your tests via gradle or maven, as outputs from those tasks will produce a report that Jenkins (and other tools) can already read, and can streamline the job setup process for your users.  But, if you can't get away with that, the above should work for you.

Comment: Good solution, I had though of, but it is a tool for a bunch of users, hence I was trying to remove this extra step. If that is the "only" way, I can just document it well enough.

Comment: What are your users generally going to do on your Jenkins server?  Are they supposed to be creating/modifying job settings?

Comment: Come to think of it, what steps does your build perform already?  Test reports from maven/gradle executions don't get zipped by default, so if you execute your tests through those, you might be able to circumvent the need for this altogether.

Comment: Its an internal tool,  by default it get zipped. There is a flag to not zip it, but we want a solution for both.  
Yes they will add/modify job settings, so they should technically be able to do it by them self with an extra step.

Comment: Okay, sounds like you're not getting out of that extra step then.  Additionally, there's a risk that the xml generated does not follow a schema recognized by the JUnit plugin, so I updated my answer in response.